# How to make this javascript, show random post by it's label?

Tags: javascript, random, blogger

I have searching about random post and it's show Math.random() function, but because my lack of knowledge about javascripting so I need your help to make this javascript work on random, thanks.

```
<script type='text/javascript'>
//<![CDATA[[
  function CompletedProject(json) {
    for (var i = 0; i < json.feed.entry.length; i++) {
      var judulPost = json.feed.entry[i].title.$t;
      var thumbPost = json.feed.entry[i].media$thumbnail.url;
      //var linkPost = json.feed.entry[i].link[1].href;
      var linkPost;  
    // Get rel=alternate for truly post url
    for (var j=0; j < json.feed.entry[i].link.length; j++)
    {
      if (json.feed.entry[i].link[j].rel == 'alternate')
      {
        linkPost = json.feed.entry[i].link[j].href;
        break;
      }
    }

      var showcompleted = '<div class="ani-item"><a href="'+linkPost+'"><img alt="'+judulPost+'" class="shine" data-original="'+thumbPost+'"/><h4>'+judulPost+'</h4></a></div>';
      document.write(showcompleted);
    }
  }
//]]>
</script>

  <script src='/feeds/posts/default/-/Complete?alt=json-in-script&amp;callback=CompletedProject'/>
```

Comment: random post? prevent cache? I usually add this code`url+"&t="+new Date()` at the end of the url

Answer (score 0):

```
var randomNumber = Math.floor(Math.random() * yourlabels.length);
yourlabels[randomNumber].yourmethod;
```

That's one way to use `Math.random()` to generate random integers for use as indexes. Here is a link to a project where I randomly generate a quote and randomly generate a background color with each click of the 'Load Quote' button. Find my `Math.random()` functions and see if you can incorporate them.

https://github.com/KyleVassella/P1_RandomQuoteGenerator/blob/gh-pages/js/script.js

`Math.floor()` is a way to round down to the nearest whole number so that `Math.random()` can be used to represent an index value.

Note that my project also has that `seen` property which represents a boolean value and is attached to each one of my quote objects - this is used with a 'while' loop to prevent the same quote or background color from randomly generating more than once until each quote has been shown. You may or may not want this feature.